# Defining different function with same name but different argument type in OpenCL 1.1

Tags: opencl

I want to define two functions with the same name but one applying a transformation on a float4 and the other one apply a transformation on float3 but it says:

> conflicting types for 'mult'

Is it impossible or something is wrong in my code?

```
typedef struct {
    float m[16];        // member elements of the matrix
} mat4;

typedef struct {
    float m[9];
} mat3;

float4 mult(mat4 matrix, float4 p) {
    return 
        matrix.m[0]     * p.x   + matrix.m[1]   * p.y + matrix.m[2]     * p.z + matrix.m[3]     * p.w +
        matrix.m[4]     * p.x   + matrix.m[5]   * p.y + matrix.m[6]     * p.z + matrix.m[7]     * p.w +
        matrix.m[8]     * p.x   + matrix.m[9]   * p.y + matrix.m[10]    * p.z + matrix.m[11]    * p.w +
        matrix.m[12]    * p.x   + matrix.m[13]  * p.y + matrix.m[14]    * p.z + matrix.m[15]    * p.w ;

}

float3 mult(mat4 matrix, float3 p) {
    return mult(matrix, float4(p, 1)).xyz;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the OpenCL built-in functions utilise function overloading to provide different variants of the same function with the same name, the OpenCL C specification does not explicitly allow function overloading in user code (and this is not a feature of C99 either).

It might be that some of the Clang-based OpenCL implementations let you use the `overloadable` function attribute, which would look something like this:

```
float4 __attribute__((overloadable)) mult(mat4 matrix, float4 p) {
    ...
}

float3 __attribute__((overloadable)) mult(mat4 matrix, float3 p) {
    ...
}
```

This is not a standard OpenCL feature however, and is not guaranteed to work on all OpenCL platforms. The OpenCL C++ kernel language proposed for OpenCL 2.1 will natively support function overloading.

Comment: And also user-defined operators so one can write `mat4 * float3` instead of a clumsy call to a function.

Comment: So, do we have operator overloading in the opencl? I mean just overloading the operator*(mat4, float3) and operator*(mat4, float4)?

Comment: @mmostajab In OpenCL 2.1 we will, but until then we have a C99-based kernel language, which does not support operator overloading.

Comment: And the sad thing is that I cannot even use OpenCL 2.0, because we only have nvidia graphic cards on our gpu clusters and I want to use their powerful cpus beside nvidia graphic cards. That's why I am going to implement my algorithms using opencl.

Comment: But anyway they will release Vulkan drivers and Vulkan has OpenCL features inside :D